# How to fetch unique multiple columns?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table like this:

[image: Click here for table]

As you can see in table there is possible to duplicate data in each column. I am trying that I have taken a textbox for searching. User is able to search by category or seller or products. But this all are unique except seller name, then how can I do this?

I tried using distinct but it returns multiple category(electronics two time) and I also tried group by but it doesn't return card reader, pen drive etc.(products of second electronics category) so how can I do this?

My model:

```
        //$this->db->distinct('category,products');
        $this->db->select('category,seller,products');
        $this->db->from('product');
        $this->db->group_by('category');
        $r=$this->db->get();
```

Comment: distinct keyword should work fine......do post what was your query when you used distinct

Comment: There is some products are repeated like in electronics(first and third record) laptops and router are repeated but i need only single time that products.

Comment: it is as above just remove the comment and group by line

Comment: that depends on which column you have applied distinct keyword on........tell me how did you inserted multiple products in products column...one by one?

Comment: i am inserting all data at a time but user can edit after inserting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query will be like this:

```
SELECT CATEGORY, GROUP_CONCAT(products) GroupedName
FROM Table
GROUP BY CATEGORY
```

Comment: Thanks this is works fine but if i want to search by seller then what is right query for it?